# Remove duplicates from list of dictionary using specific keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a list of dictionary as follow:

```
a = [{'author':'John','country':'us','gender':'male'},
     {'author':'Sean','country':'uk','gender':'male'},
     {'author':'Sean','country':'russia','gender':'male'},
     {'author':'Mike','country':'japan','gender':'male'}]
```

So now, only based on the `author` I want to remove duplicates from this list of dictionary irrespective of other key values. Output should be as follow with entry no. 3  removed. (`author` is repeated)

```
    a = [{'author':'John','country':'us','gender':'male'},
         {'author':'Sean','country':'uk','gender':'male'},
         {'author':'Mike','country':'japan','gender':'male'}]
```

Please suggest the shortest way possible!

Comment: use a set to store the authors you've already seen

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? Based on that, what did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please do some research and after ask question

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes to my mind and should do the trick:

```
list(dict([(elem['author'], elem) for elem in a]).values())
```

although there might exist some cleaner and/or shorter way.

Answer (score 1):

I think pandas should do this for us:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=None)

a = df.drop_duplicates(['author']).to_dict(orient='record')

print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'author': 'John', 'country': 'us', 'gender': 'male'},
 {'author': 'Sean', 'country': 'uk', 'gender': 'male'},
 {'author': 'Mike', 'country': 'japan', 'gender': 'male'}]
```

Or if you care about memory and don't want to store both `a` and `df`, create the dataframe into `a` (`a = pd.DataFrame(a, index=None)`).